# PHP: Images file is not uploading on the server?

Tags: php, file-upload

When I upload file on my localhost it works fine. But when I upload it on the server it doesn't work. Image is displaying on that page correctly from same directory but it has problem in uploading file to that directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Belvic Print - Home page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Printing template">
    <meta name="author" content="Netbase">
    <!--Add css lib-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code_adimn.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


    <style>
        body{
            position: relative;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .main-container{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .submit_button{
            border: none;
            margin-top: 5%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        label.myLabel input[type="file"] {
            position: fixed;
            top: -1000px;
        }
        .col-lg-offset-4{
            margin-bottom: 5%;
        }

        .row{
            margin-top: 3%;
        }
        /***** Example custom styling *****/
        .myLabel {
            /*border: 2px solid #AAA;*/
            padding: 10px;

            margin-top: 5%;
            background: #DDD;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .myLabel:hover {
            background: #CCC;
        }

        .myLabel:active {
            background: #CCF;
        }

        .myLabel :invalid + span {
            color: #A44;
        }

        .myLabel :valid + span {
            color: #4A4;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid main-container">

    <div class="navibar">
        <div class="fa fa-bars"> <span> Menu Bar </span></div>
        <ul>
            <div class="fa fa-close"></div>
            <h2 class="admin">Admin Panel</h2>
            <li><a href="#first">Image 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second">Image 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third">Image 3</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row img-row">
        <div id="first" class="rows col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-4">
            <?php
            include("db.php");
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=1");
            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            ?>

            <img src="<?php echo "../images/slider/home/" . $record['image1']; ?>" alt="" width="100%">//This image is displaying correctly from same directory
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="slider.php" method="POST" >
                <label class="myLabel">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile1"/>
                    <span>Change Picture</span>
                </label>
                <input name="submit1" type="submit" class="submit_button">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>

            <form action="slider.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label name="description">Enter the heading: </label>
                <input type="text" name="heading1" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter the heading" value="<?php echo $record['image2']; ?>">
                <br>
                <label name="description">Enter the Description</label>
                <textarea name="description1" class="form-control"  rows="3"><?php echo $record['image3'];} ?></textarea>
                <input name="submit_content1" type="submit" class="pull-left submit_button">

            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="second" class="rows col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-4">
            <?php
            $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=1");
            while ($record1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo "../images/slider/home/" . $record1['image4']; ?>" alt="kk" width="100%">
            <form action="slider.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label class="myLabel">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile2"/>
                    <span>Upload Picture</span>
                </label>
                <input name="submit2" type="submit" class="submit_button">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
            <form action="slider.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label name="description">Enter the heading: </label>
                <input type="text" name="heading2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the heading" value="<?php echo $record1['image5']; ?>">
                <br>
                <label name="description">Enter the Description</label>
                <textarea name="description2" class="form-control" rows="3"><?php echo $record1['image6'];} ?></textarea>
                <input name="submit_content2" type="submit" class="pull-left submit_button">

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="third" class="rows col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-4">

            <?php
            $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=1");
            while ($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo "../images/slider/home/" . $record2['image7']; ?>" alt="" width="100%">
            <form action="slider.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label class="myLabel">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile3"/>
                    <span>Upload Picture</span>
                </label>
                <input name="submit3" type="submit" class="submit_button">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
            <form action="slider.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label name="description">Enter the heading: </label>
                <input type="text" name="heading3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the heading" value="<?php echo $record2['image8']; ?>">
                <br>
                <label name="description">Enter the Description</label>
                <textarea name="description3" class="form-control" rows="3"><?php echo $record2['image9'];} ?></textarea>
                <input name="submit_content3" type="submit" class="pull-left submit_button">

            </form>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {


    $type = $_FILES["myfile1"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["myfile1"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["myfile1"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["myfile1"]["error"];
    if ($_FILES["myfile1"]["error"] < 1) {
        if (exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile1"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_PNG && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile1"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile1"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile1"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_ICO) {
            echo 'There is problem with image file or file is not image';

        } else {
            $name = "image_" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/slider/home/" . $name);

            if ($_FILES["myfile1"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Some error in file upload";
            } else {

                $sql = "UPDATE image SET image1='$name' WHERE id=1";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && $upload) {
                    echo "Refresh the page to see the effect";
                } else {
                    echo "Some error while updating image";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "There is error in image file";
    }

}









//For image 2

if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {


    $type = $_FILES["myfile2"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["myfile2"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["myfile2"]["error"];
    if ($_FILES["myfile2"]["error"] < 1) {
        if (exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_PNG && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_ICO) {
            echo 'There is problem with image file or file is not image';

        } else {
            $name = "image_" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/slider/home/" . $name);

            if ($_FILES["myfile2"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Some error in file upload";
            } else {

                $sql = "UPDATE image SET image4='$name' WHERE id=1";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && $upload) {
                    echo "Refresh the page to see the effect";
                } else {
                    echo "Some error while updating image";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "There is error in image file";
    }

}

//For image 3


if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {


    $type = $_FILES["myfile3"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["myfile3"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["myfile3"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["myfile3"]["error"];
    if ($_FILES["myfile3"]["error"] < 1) {
        if (exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile3"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_PNG && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile3"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile3"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF && exif_imagetype($_FILES["myfile3"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_ICO) {
            echo 'There is problem with image file or file is not image';

        } else {
            $name = "image_" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/slider/home/" . $name);

            if ($_FILES["myfile3"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Some error in file upload";
            } else {

                $sql = "UPDATE image SET image7='$name' WHERE id=1";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && $upload) {
                    echo "Refresh the page to see the effect";
                } else {
                    echo "Some error while updating image";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "There is error in image file";
    }

}



//For content 1
if (isset($_POST['submit_content1'])) {

    $heading1 = $_POST['heading1'];
    $description1 = $_POST['description1'];

    $update1 = "UPDATE image SET image2='$heading1', image3='$description1' WHERE id=1";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $update1)) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}


//For content 2
if (isset($_POST['submit_content2'])) {

    $heading2 = $_POST['heading2'];
    $description2 = $_POST['description2'];

    $update2 = "UPDATE image SET image5='$heading2', image6='$description2' WHERE id=1";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $update2)) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}



//For content 3
if (isset($_POST['submit_content3'])) {

    $heading3 = $_POST['heading3'];
    $description3 = $_POST['description3'];

    $update3 = "UPDATE image SET image8='$heading3', image6='$description3' WHERE id=1";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $update3)) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

?>


</body>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: check for folder permissions, usual issue when code works in one spot but not another

Comment: @Fred-ii- But image is being displayed from that folder correctly

Comment: I for one do not see any error checking, nor do we know if your hosted site has it on by default. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php if that is the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `<img src="<?php echo "../images/slider/home/" . $record['image1']; ?>" alt="" width="100%">`

Comment: I use same folder for uploading

Comment: *Images file is not uploading on the server?* - the question is about a file not being uploaded, yet you show us an `<img src...`, I am not grasping the question here.

Comment: I want to show that image is displaying from that folder correctly. But when I use that directory address for uploading it doesn't work

Comment: you need to use `is_uploaded_file($temp)` for security reason before moving it. And be sure youre script have the right to write into the folder :)

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()` I have found this error on the server

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` < place that in a single file and see what extensions are installed or not. If any of those exif functions are not available for you to use, then you will need to contact your web host to see what they can do about it. If it's a question of security, then you may not be able to use your code in its present state. @ZainFarooq However, some hosts allow you to place an `php.ini` file somewhere on your web space in order to add to the present system settings it's already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this 2 lines on php.ini (or unquote it)

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

and like i said use `is_uploaded_file` before moving files :)

Comment: is php.ini present on the online server?

Comment: yes, but it depends what kind of server is it. It's a private or a shared server, do you have a cpanel or other stuff to create web domain  folder ?

Comment: check here :https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/56Docs/PHP+Extensions+and+Applications+Package  its under PHP Extensions and Applications Package Installer